# Integral over angular spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I have to face an integral of the form
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
\frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi+\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}$$
where the angle $\psi$ is constant and it is considered to be between $0$ and $\pi$. Is there any way to solve this? Maybe try some sort of shift of the variables of integration? If not, can I know for sure that it diverges, probably at $(\theta,\phi)=(\psi,0)$, and how it diverges (i.e. logarithmically, linearly, etc)?

What about the limits $\psi\rightarrow0$ or $\psi\rightarrow\pi$?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** What if I know that $\psi$ is a small, but non-zero angle? Am I allowed to Taylor expand in $\psi$? Then the integral will be convergent at all orders, right? Does this contradict the traditional method of simply trying to evaluate the integral?

Comment: [Substituting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ may work for the $\theta$ integral. It gives$$4\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\infty dt\,\frac{bt+2ct^2+bt^3}{(1+t^2)^2(1-a-2bct+(1+a)t^2)}$$where $a=\cos\psi$, $b=\sqrt{1-a^2}=\sin\psi$, and $c=\cos\phi$. The antiderivative with respect to $t$ is elementary (use partial fractions) though evaluating it as $t\to\infty$ is a bit tricky.

Comment: OTOH, you could consider swapping the variables and compute the integral wrt $\phi$ by converting it to a complex contour integral via $z=e^{i\phi}$, which gives$$\frac ib \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \sin\theta \oint\limits_{|z|=1} dz 
\frac{z^2+\frac{2b}{\sin\theta}z + 1}{z^3-\frac{2(1-a\cos\theta)}{b\sin\theta}z^2+z}$$then apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Hi @user170231. I have tried that and the integral I get from using the residue theorem is pretty complicated. I don't know how to solve this. Is it possible, though, that the integral does not diverge and has solutions that are not real?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, the denominator has a singularity at $(\theta,\phi)=(\psi,0)$. At this point, the numerator is just $2\sin^2\psi$, so unless $ \psi=0$ or $\pi$, there’s nothing to cancel the singularity. To better understand the nature of the singularity, consider the integral

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
\frac1{1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta}\;,
$$

which has the same type of singularity. The denominator is $1$ minus the scalar product of the unit vectors corresponding to $(\theta,\phi)$ and $(\psi,0)$, and since the scalar product is invariant under rotations and the integral is over the entire solid angle, the value of the integral doesn’t depend on the value of $(\psi,0)$. So we can use $(0,0)$ instead, yielding

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
\frac1{1-\cos\theta}=2\pi\left[\log(1-\cos\theta)\right]_0^\pi\;.
$$

Thus, there’s a logarithmic divergence at $\theta=0$, and thus a logarithmic divergence at $(\psi,0)$ in the original integral.

For $\psi=0$, the original integral is

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
\frac{\sin\theta\cos\phi}{1-\cos\theta}\;.
$$

Now both the numerator and the denominator are quadratic in $\theta$ at $\theta=0$, so there’s no singularity, and then the integral over $\cos\theta$ yields $0$. The same happens when $\psi=\pi$.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. So, you seem to suggest that because of rotational invariance, the integral does not depend on $\psi$ and therefore we can set it to be zero. I think I understand that reasoning, but I have a follow up question: can this be seen by some sort of change in variables of the integral?

Comment: @schris38: No, that's not at all what I said. Please read the answer again. I wrote that the type of the singularity doesn't depend on the details of the numerator as long as it's not $0$ at the singularity, so in those cases we can drop the numerator and then use rotational invariance to find the type of the singularity. It's still a singularity, I didn't say anything about "setting the integral to be zero". I merely pointed out that it's $0$ at $\psi=0$ and $\psi=\pi$ (where the numerator cancels the singularity).

Comment: Appologies @joriki for missunderstanding your answer. So, you mean to say that the integral is zero at $\psi=0,\pi$? And you are using the rotational invariance of the denominator to deduce that, right? But you have no information on the behavior of the integral at any other value of $\psi$ between $0$ and $\pi$, other than it diverges at $(\theta,\phi)=(\psi,0)$? Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @schris38: The integral for $\psi=0,\pi$ is zero because it factors as $\cos\phi$ times a function of $\theta$ and the integral over $\cos\phi$ is $0$. I'm not sure what you mean by "you have no information on the behavior other than it diverges". I showed that the divergence is logarithmic. That's what you'd specifically asked about. What else is there to say?

Comment: Okay, I see... Sorry for being stubborn. So, the integral is logarithmically divergent, unless if $\psi=0,\pi$. Thanks so much for the patience