# Integral over spherical angular coordinates vol. 2

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

This question is heavily related to this old post of mine [Integral over angular spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664880/integral-over-angular-spherical-coordinates). However, now I have a different integral, which is, I believe, convergent. I write down the integral and then I will explain why I believe that it is convergent. The integral is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
\frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}$$
where $0<\psi<\pi$.

My line of reasoning is as follows:

1. Observe that the integral has a single pole at $(\theta,\phi)=(\psi,0)$
2. Break down the integral, according to
   $$\begin{align*}
   & \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
   \frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)} 
   \\ 
   &=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\psi}\sin\theta d\theta
   \frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}\\
   &\quad +
   \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{\psi}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta
   \frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}
   \end{align*}$$
3. Consider the first integral:
   $$I_1(\psi)=
   \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\psi}\sin\theta d\theta
   \frac{(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\sin\psi)}{(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}$$
   and shift variables, according to $\theta=\psi-\epsilon$, and then
   $$I_1(\psi)=
   \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\Delta_1}\sin(\psi-\epsilon) d\epsilon
   \frac{\Big[\sin(\psi-\epsilon)\cos\phi-\sin\psi\Big]}{\Big[1-\sin\psi\sin(\psi-\epsilon)\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos(\psi-\epsilon)\Big]}$$
4. Now the pole is shifted to $(\epsilon,\phi)=(0,0)$. Expanding the integrand around this point , assuming, hence, that the two angular variables $\epsilon$ and $\phi$ are small, yields
   $$I_1(\psi)=\sin\psi
   \int_0^{\Delta_2}d\phi\int_0^{\Delta_1} d\epsilon
   \frac{2\epsilon\cos\psi}{(\epsilon^2+\phi^2\sin^2\psi)}$$
   where I have restricted the integration interval, such that it makes sense to expand and neglect higher order terms (as they are smaller).
5. Those integrals can actually be done
   $$\begin{align*}
   I_1(\psi)&=\sin(2\psi)\int_0^{\Delta_2}d\phi\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg(1+\frac{\Delta_1^2}{\phi^2\sin^2\psi}\bigg)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\psi)\bigg[
   \Delta_2\ln\bigg(\frac{\Delta_1^2/\sin^2\psi+\Delta_2^2}{\Delta_2^2}\bigg)+
   2\frac{\Delta_1}{\sin\psi}\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{\Delta_2\sin\psi}{\Delta_1}\Big)
   \bigg]
   \end{align*}$$
   which is finite. Similar steps can be taken to show that $I_2(\psi)$ is finite...

Is this line of reasoning correct? Meaning, if there is no divergence near the pole, there should not be a divergence anywhere in the interval of integration, right?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume $0<\psi<\pi$?

Comment: Yes, actually @DavidH , sorry for not mentioning it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in convergence, once you remark that there
is a single pole at $\left({\theta} , {\phi}\right) = \left({\psi} , 0\right)$, you can prove
convergence by a simple Taylor expansion around the pole. The denominator has the expansion

\begin{equation}1-\sin  {\psi} \sin  {\theta} \cos  {\phi}-\cos  {\psi} \cos  {\theta} = \frac{1}{2} {\left({\theta}-{\psi}\right)}^{2}+\frac{1}{2} {\sin }^{2} \left({\psi}\right) {{\phi}}^{2}+o \left({r}^{2}\right)\end{equation}

where $ r = \sqrt{{\left({\theta}-{\psi}\right)}^{2}+{{\phi}}^{2}}$
and for the numerator,

\begin{equation}\sin  {\theta} \cos  {\phi}-\sin  {\psi} = \cos  \left({\psi}\right) \left({\theta}-{\psi}\right)+o \left(r\right)\end{equation}

It follows that the function below the integral is

\begin{equation}F \left({\theta} , {\phi}\right) = O \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) \in  {L}_{\text{loc}}^{1} \left(d {\theta} d {\phi}\right)\end{equation}
which is locally integrable around the pole.

Comment: Hi @Gribouillis and thank you so much for your answer. Saying that it is locally integrable means that the integral of the expression is finite around the pole (with the pole being included), right? If this is the case, and given that we only have one pole, i.e. only a single point for which the integral may be divergent, does this mean that the whole integral converges??

Comment: Saying that it is locally integrable around the pole means that there is a neighborhood of the pole on which the integral converges. This is implied by the above Taylor expansion. The whole integral converges because outside this neighborhood of the pole, the function $F$ is continuous, hence bounded and we integrate on a bounded domain.

Comment: Btw, the enumerator also has a $\sin\theta$ term from the solid angle integration measure. Does it affect the convergence? Okay, sorry, this is just $\sin\psi$ plus higher order corrections, sorry :)

Comment: No because multiplying an integrable function by a bounded function gives an integrable function. Remember that "integrable" means "absolutely integrable" in Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!!!